# Replace an element of a List with a concrete Id

Tags: java, array, android

I want to replace an object of a `List` with another one. To find the item to replace I need to check the field `id` of the object to find what item is the same.

```
public void changeItemInformation(@NonNull Suggestion suggestion) {
    if (mSuggestions != null) {
        int itemChanged = -1;
        int index = -1;
        for (Suggestion suggestionItem : mSuggestions) {
            index++;
            if(suggestionItem.getId() == suggestion.getId()){
                itemChanged = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (itemChanged != -1) {
            mSuggestions.set(itemChanged, suggestion);
            notifyItemChanged(itemChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

- `mSuggestions` is the list of `Suggestion`s.
- `suggestion` is the new item to replace the old one.
- `notifyItemChanged()` is an Android method to notify a `RecyclerView` that an element changed.

Is there a better way to do this? There aren't any perform problems, the list always has a maximum of 100 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like your `itemChanged` and `index` variables.
If you iterate over a list and keep track of the index anyway, why don't you use an ordinary `for`-loop?
In addition to that, you also just copy the value of your `index` variable and break out of the loop; you could easily merge all that to one loop with one condition.
This:

```
    int itemChanged = -1;
    int index = -1;
    for (Suggestion suggestionItem : mSuggestions) {
        index++;
        if(suggestionItem.getId() == suggestion.getId()){
            itemChanged = index;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (itemChanged != -1) {
        mSuggestions.set(itemChanged, suggestion);
        notifyItemChanged(itemChanged);
    }
```

would become this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < mSuggestions.size(); index++) {
    if(mSuggestions.get(index).getId() == suggestion.getId()){
        mSuggestions.set(index, suggestion);
        notifyItemChanged(index);
        break;
    }
}
```

You don't even need to check if there is an item to replace, because if the condition is never met, it's never going to execute the code inside of it.